# Prevent Next button from going to next page

Tags: javascript, validation, wizard

I'm facing a problem with wizard validation in MVC. I want the code to check if a field is empty or not before jumping to the next page. I am using [this wizard](https://github.com/farhan2986/angular-ui-fuelux-wizard) in my project. Here is my .cshtml page:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 text-right bottom-prev-next">
    <button id="vnBtnNext" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-next" data-attr="{{currentStepIndex==steps.length-1?currentStepIndex:currentStepIndex}}">{{currentStepIndex==steps.length-1?'Finish':'Next'}}<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    <button id="vnBtnPrev" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-prev pull-left"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>Prev</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on("click", "#vnBtnNext", function (e) {

    if ($('#vnBtnNext').html().indexOf("Next") != -1 && $('#vnBtnNext').attr('data-attr') == "1") {
        if ($('input[name=FirstName]').val() == "") {

            $("input[name=FirstName]").css("background-color", "lightyellow");
            $('input[name=FirstName]').focus();
            alert('Please enter the First Name in English');
        }
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are still going to next page is following line of codes in your wizard library.

```
//line no. 29-33
var btnNexts = document.querySelectorAll( '.btn-next' );
for (var j = 0; j < btnNexts.length; ++j) {
    angular.element(btnNexts[j]).attr('ng-click','showNextStep()');
    angular.element(btnNexts[j]).attr('ng-disabled', '!hasNext() && !isFinish()');
}
```

and `showNextStep` is as follow.

```
$scope.showNextStep = function(){$scope.toggleSteps($scope.currentStepIndex + 1, true);}
```

You need to change `showNextStep` implementation in such a way that it does not toggle until all validations are passed. Basically what I'm saying is you need to execute the following line conditionally if and only if all validations are passed in the current step.

```
//line no. 74
$scope.toggleSteps($scope.currentStepIndex + 1, true);
```

I guess this is fairly enough to get you started with.

**EDIT**
There are a number of ways you can make this change either by extending this library which will take validator for each step. Or you can modify line no. 74 to include your validator. Specified repo allows you to freely use and edit source code. Following is an example

```
$scope.showNextStep = function(){

          var validationPassed = true; // make validator for each step and call that validor based on step which will return true/false or if you want sophistication then let them return object with validation message.

          // This is proof of concept and needs to be in function.
          if ($('input[name=FirstName]').val() == "") {

               $("input[name=FirstName]").css("background-color", "lightyellow");
               $('input[name=FirstName]').focus();
               alert('Please enter the First Name in English');
               validationPassed  = false;
          }



  if(validationPassed)
    $scope.toggleSteps($scope.currentStepIndex + 1, true);
  else
    //Do not toggle step and show validation message.

}
```

I guess you get the idea.

Or you can try e.preventDefault(), and e.stopPropogation() in your custom event handler you have written in your question. I don't know how angular behave to this but you can try this as well.

Comment: Makes sense. But how do I add the validation rules to wizard.js? The validation rules are something like this: if(('#firstName').val() == "") {//tell user that they must enter first name}else{//go to next page}

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have previously tried e.preventDefault() but it does not work. stopPorpogartion gives me an error saying it is not a function. As for adding a validator, how do I send a value to wizard.js that does the validation?

Comment: You have step information in wizard based on that step number access step container and in step container, you will find all controls. Then use whatever validation rules you want to apply.

Comment: I'm confused. How do I send a value from my .cshtml page to the wizard.js?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Your answer worked! I just moved the wizard.js code into a script tag inside the .cshtml page. Then, I edited the $scope.showNextStep function to include validation before toggling the steps. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

TO prevent events in JavaScript

You should use **e.preventDefault();**

add this code in the **else clause**

```
e.preventDefault();
return false;
```

Comment: try **e.stoppropagation()**